# How to Configure Prometheus running as container to scrape metrics generated by other application as container

Tags: python, docker, containers, prometheus

I am figuring out Network issues between Prometheus and python application within Docker. How can I make Prometheus able to scrape metrics generated by the python application within docker, and shows it on the Prometheus end.

Docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:v2.0.0
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    links:
      - web
  web:
    image: python:3.5-alpine
    build: ./test
    ports:
     - "5000:8002"
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.5-alpine
ADD app1.py /
RUN pip install prometheus_client
CMD ["python", "./app1.py"]
EXPOSE 8002
```

prometheus.yml

```
# my global config
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s 
  evaluation_interval: 15s 
  external_labels:
      monitor: 'codelab-monitor'
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['docker.for.mac.host.internal:9090']
  - job_name: 'python_app'
    metrics_path: /  
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['docker.for.mac.host.internal:8002']
```

So far, I can see Prometheus is running well, and its targets' status shows UP
on 'docker.for.mac.host.internal:9090' and 'docker.for.mac.host.internal:8002'

And the python application is running as well, I can see the output metrics on the port

So everything should work by now, Prometheus can scrape metrics over the specified port. However there is no such metrics there.

Comment: you have created a link with name 'web', have you tried to use it in 'static_configs.targets'? something like 'web:8002'. IMO 'docker.for.mac.host.internal' still hits same container - the one with prometheus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the relative portion of a prometheus.yml file I'm using:

```
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: 'prometheus'

    # Override the global default and scrape targets from this job every 5 seconds.
    scrape_interval: 5s
    scrape_timeout: 10s

    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.

    target_groups:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090']

  - job_name: app-server
    target_groups:
      - targets: ['dbserver:5000']
```

Note also you'll want to verify by hitting the various URLs yourself that there are metrics to pull.

```
curl "http://dbserver:5000/metrics"
```

Docker for Mac. The app running on dbserver:5000 is running on the Mac, not inside Docker. If it were inside Docker, I got that to work by making sure it was exposed and that I could hit it with curl from a Mac terminal window.